# How to send information back and forth from a javascript file to a python file

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

So I have an html file with javascript and a python file. In the javascript file, the user enters a string. In the python, I would like it to search it in an api, and then return the string to be displayed in the html file. How do I do this? I have looked up how to use AJAX and get/post methods, but nothing has worked so far. Also, I should mention I am using flask.

Comment: you can maybe write to a text file and then get the contents from the other python file, and yes tis is a naive method

Comment: Hey, could you detail this? Write to a file in javascript, then read it with python, write with python and then pick it up with javascript? How would the two files know when to read and write?

Comment: I mean you said you were using flask which uses python, right?

Comment: If yes, then you can use open(“name”,”w”), a python method, to create a file

Comment: Yes, I am using the flask frame work

Comment: Yes, I am aware, but how do I get the python file to respond only after js has written to the file?

Comment: Also you can use SQL or NoSQL databases, one good library would be sqlite3

Comment: So you mean like write to sql and then read from there?

Comment: You can create a loop in you python file, which check in the file every 1 second, this is a pretty complex idea, it will need planning to execute

Answer (score 1):

The basic mechanics of having an HTML page communicate directly with another program is web server programming.  If you want the web server to execute python, then consider setting up a [Django server](https://www.djangoproject.com/).  Learning how to set up a web server and getting the two programs to talk with each other may take a while if it is your first time.